# I am having an issue with an Ocaml function that takes in two inputs and is supposed ti give a specific output

Tags: ocaml

I'm working on a homework problem and usually, I have an idea of why an error is occurring, however, with these two I have no idea what's going on. I'm not sure if it's the pattern matching or if it's how I'm trying to solve the problem after the pattern match.

```
Given a STRING LIST and INT return a STRING LIST 
that contains all the strings with a length greater than the given int

    let rec long_strings (l: string list) (i: int) : string list = 
            match l with
            | [] -> []
            | head :: tail -> if (String.length head > i) 
                                 then head :: (long_strings tail) 
                                 else (long_strings tail)
```

ERROR

```
This expression has type int -> string list
but an expression was expected of type string list
```

Another similar issue...

```
(*Given an INT LIST and INT divide the numbers in the given int 
 list by the given int and return an (INT * INT) LIST containing 
  the dividend and the remainder*)
let rec remainders (l: int list) (i: int) : (int * int) list = 
        match l with
        | [] -> []
        | head :: tail -> ((head / i), (head mod num)) :: (remainders tail)
;;
```

ERROR

```
This expression has type int -> (int * int) list
but an expression was expected of type (int * int) list
```

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up functions with function applications. The `->` types are functions, the one without them are results of application of said functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an argument. The type of `long_strings` is `string list -> int -> string list`. Thus if you apply `long_strings` to a string list, you get a function: `int -> string list`.
For instance, one could define

```ml
let list = ["1"; "12"; "123"]
let filter_list = long_strings list
let _ = assert ( filter_list 0 = ["1"; "12"; "123"] )
let _ = assert ( filter_list 2 = ["123"] )
```

However, in

```ml
head :: long_strings tail
```

you are expecting `long_strings tail` to be a list.
Thus the error message

> This expression has type int -> string list
> but an expression was expected of type string list

which is telling you that `long_strings tail` is not a list but a function that takes a `int` and returns a `string_list`.

In other words, you forgot the `i` argument.

Comment: I had thought the error indicated I was producing an incorrect output type. I added the appropriate arguments to my recurssive calls and can move on to testing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You *were* producing an incorrect output type. OCaml functions are usually "curried" which means you can leave off some of the arguments and get an intermediate function back instead of the final answer. If the code is expecting the final answer, this intermediate function type is the wrong type. It's not too hard to get used to this pattern (IMHO).